# SQL Server - get next value from sequence without advancing the current_value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that verifies that the NEXT VALUE from a Sequence will be equal to the max number from a table, plus 1.  I'm doing this by comparing the table number to the sequence's current_value from sys.sequences.

However, I am having trouble with this because I'm not sure how to differentiate between the case where the current_value is '1' and the NEXT VALUE will be '1', vs. the case where the NEXT VALUE will be '2'.

I do not want to actually call NEXT VALUE as i don't want to advance the count of the Sequence.

For example, this case:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  testseq AS bigint START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 500000
select current_value from sys.sequences where name = 'testseq'
```

where current_value is 1 and next value will be 1

vs.

```
select NEXT VALUE for testseq
select current_value from sys.sequences where name = 'testseq'
```

where current_value is 1 and next value will be 2.

I will not be able to change the properties of the Sequence.  Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but when would it be possible that the current value is 1 *and* the next value is also 1?

Comment: If The next value = to the max value from a table plus 1  
then current value in the sequence = max value from a table right? or am I missing something here, I don't understand the idea behind these... seems like unnecessary nonsense.

Comment: `select current_value + increment from sys.sequences where name = 'testseq'`?

Comment: @Siyual In my example above.  if you run those 4 lines you will see it returns a current_value of 1, a next value of 1, and a current_value of 1 again.

Comment: Let me ask the dumb question: why not just let the sequence do what it does and return you the next value in the sequence? Why does your site procedure need to verify anything?

Comment: I agree with @BenThul.  Trying to peek at the sequence is bound to cause problems since there's nothing stopping another query from calling NEXT VALUE FOR.  It's building a race condition into your application.

Comment: @BenThul   I'm sure that is normally great advice.  In this particular instance I am trying to use this code only for verification that things are working correctly after moving over from using identity columns in a data warehouse to sequences.  There are lots of tables involved, and there is the possibility that some of the sequences could have been created with an incorrect starting point, and i'm trying to verify against that in an automated way.  I'm doing this verification in a database that only I have access to, so i know there won't be contention issues.

Comment: So don't try to make the sequence hapless. That is, have the starting point in your new system be such that there's no chance for overlap. Alternatively, you can get which sequence is associated with which table through sys.default_constraints, call next value on each of those, and compare that with max value on the table. That would be a one-time operation and you can be done with it.

Answer (score 7):

Works for SQL Server 2017 and newer:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN last_used_value IS NULL
THEN CAST(current_value as bigint)
ELSE CAST(current_value as bigint) + 1
END AS next_val
FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'sequence_name'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select cast(current_value as int) + cast(increment as int) from sys.sequences where name = 'testseq'
```

Comment: This doesn't work, which is what i was trying to get at in my original comment.  `CREATE SEQUENCE testseq AS bigint START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 500000; select cast(current_value as int) + cast(increment as int) from sys.sequences where name = 'testseq'; /*this returns 2*/ select NEXT VALUE for testseq /*this returns 1*/`

Comment: Just to be clear, the case where I'm getting the unexpected result is after the sequence is created, but before you get a value from it.  At that point the current_value is 1 and the next_value will be 1.  After that the current_value is still 1 and the next_value will be 2.  After that the current_value will be 2 and the next_value will be 3.  And so on.